# is there any procedure to call a button from secondary activity to main activity

Tags: android

How can I use buttons from secondary activity to main activity.
I want to access the function of buttons in main activity, when I click on a button in secondary activity.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can access button click via intent mechanism. When you stay at visible activity you can't see any views of the first one. So, when you move from 2 activity to 1 activity you use `Intent()`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

You can pass some data via intent and click the button:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("clickBtn",0);
startActivity(intent);
```

as you can see at the code above you send data here:

```
intent.putIntExtra("clickBtn",0);
```

You can set for example 0 for clicking and 1 for preventing click. And finally you will need to handle incoming data from intent:

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
Int variable = intent.getIntExtra("clickBtn",1);
```

and right now after getting data from 2 activity you can work with it:

```
switch (variable ) {
case  (0):
  //button click;
  break;
case (1):
   // no action
   break;

default:
   //some default action
   break;
}
```

This is it :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I want to access the button through Id in main activity from secondary activity. I placed a button in secondary activity with R.Id.button1. I want to call that id in main activity. when I click on button in secondary activity then functions will be perform in main activity. Thanks